# insert all column as 1 column for blob file

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to direct insert all columns to 1 column for blob file. Or do I need to outfile first the table so that I can upload it as blob. If ever possible here is my imaginary query, something like this:

```
insert into blob("file") values ('va1','va2','val3')
```

Any suggestions/comments thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql, what you're thinking of is `concat_ws`. This allows you to combine the results from multiple columns.

```
INSERT INTO mytable(value1)
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', value1, value2, value3)
    FROM table
    LIMIT 1;
```

However, in this case, you don't use the `VALUES` syntax, you simply run your query.

Here is a fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57abb/1/0

Comment: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause 0.000 sec

Comment: When I answered, I was using that as an example. I changed it